# Replace value in column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF

```
***********************
Product       Rate      Imputed_rate      min_rate

1              0        10                5
2              0        4                 7
3              0        34                2
4              0        3                 8
***************************
```

I want to replace the row when Rate=0 ; with the 'min_rate' only if 'Imputed_rate'<min_rate

---

What is the best way to do this?

---

Desired Output:

---

```
Product       Rate      Imputed_rate      min_rate

1             0         10                5
2             7         4                 7
3             0         34                2
4             8         3                 8
***************************
```

Comment: Show your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.where` is your friend https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
df['Rate'] = np.where(((df['Rate'] == 0) & (df['Imputed_rate'] < df['min_rate'])), df['min_rate'],df['Rate'])
```

it is basically an if then else for rows in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer without using numpy:

```
df['Rate'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['min_rate'] if row['Imputed_rate'] < row['min_rate'] else row['Rate'],axis = 1)

#Output:
   Product  Rate  Imputed_rate  min_rate
0        1     0            10         5
1        2     7             4         7
2        3     0            34         2
3        4     8             3         8
```